# How to programmatically refresh VS code editor in VSIX extension

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2015, visual-studio-extensions, vsix

How can I enforce refresh of the Visual Studio's code editor?

I have a VSIX extension which implements custom coloring via VS tagging mechanism. The extension has some settings, for example to turn off coloring. They are integrated into VS settings via DialogPage mechanism, just like in the MSDN example. I use them in my ITaggerProvider CreateTagger implementation to decide if I should use tagger.

When I change the coloring settings the coloring of the opened documents isn't refreshed. But I can close and reopen them and then the documents are colored according to the new setting's value.
Is there a way to tell Visual Studio to refresh the code editor and recreate taggers for it?

Comment: Do you save the settings/projects after you change it? Not found the refresh function even if in the default code Editor, maybe you could think about re-opening the code Editor automatically or others.

Comment: Yes, I do save my settings after changes. Actually I used a class derived from DialogPage. It uses VS default mechanism to save settings.

Comment: Actually, I've found a workaround. You can declare the event SettingsChanged in the Options class and raise it (if needed) when settings are saved. Then you can subscribe your tagger on it and in the handler raise TagsChanged event. To prevent memory leak the tagger should implement IDisposable.Dispose in which it unsubscribes from the event.  This works for me. Still I think it doesn't answer my original question - how to refresh the editor

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may try to close the document and open it again.

```
    string path = dte.ActiveDocument.FullName;
    dte.ActiveDocument.Save();
    dte.ActiveDocument.Close();
    dte.ItemOperations.OpenFile(path);
```

**Edit:** A much better way is to raise the event declared in your tagger class (which implements ITagger interface).

Comment: Wouldn't this lead to the effects visible to user e.g. strange close/reopen, losing position in the document tab well?

Comment: @SENya Yes, you are right. It's 'a' solution and I understand not the best one.

Comment: Raising the TagsChanged event is indeed the path I have taken. It works great so far.